# Composer throws [ReflectionException] Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I installed the latest version (1.0.0. stable) of composer and in my Yii2 project I typed this:

`php composer.phar update`

It gives me this error:

> [ReflectionException] Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist

> [ErrorException] Declaration of Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository::whatProvides()  should be compatible with Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository::whatProvides(Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool $pool, $name, $bypassFilters = false)

Can someone help me how to fix this?

Here's my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "@dev",
        "golonka/bbcodeparser": "^2.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your `composer.json`?

Comment: @Federico there it is

Answer (score 180, accepted):

About nine days ago (around end of March, 2016), `Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository::whatProvides` api changed. ([#2668](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2661))
So, if you have installed `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` globally, you should update it. You can do that with:

```
php composer.phar global update fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this command ends with the same error. Solved by removing `~/.composer` directory and reinstalling `fxp/composer-asset-plugin`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I've added `--no-plugins` option to the answer.

Comment: We are having same issue but running composer with sudo works fine. Don't know it's correct?

Comment: Did not help. After a second call I get 'Nothing to install or update'. Then update will create the same errors agains. Any further ideas?

Comment: removing ~/.composer/vendor/fxp && ./composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0" fixed it for me

Answer (score 68):

Try this one if update doesn't work.

```
composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins
```

Comment: this fixed mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

I ended up resolving the issue by removing the `fxp` directory from the `.composer` directory. On my setup, this does the trick:

```
rm -rf ~/.composer/vendor/fxp
```

Now when something needs it, it can just re-download the updated plugin.

Comment: For those using Windows:  C:\Users\<UserId>\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor

Answer (score 7):

Try to edit your global `composer.json` by running:

`vi ~/.composer/composer.json` then make sure you have this line on it:

```
{
    "require": {
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "1.1.*"
    }
}
```

the above answers did not work for me because the version of my `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` was like `1.1-beta04`, when I changed it to `"1.1.8"` and run updating command:

```
php /usr/bin/composer global update fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins
```

It fixed the problem. but without editing my global `composer.json`, it was giving me this error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>           - Installation request for fxp/composer-asset-plugin 1.0.0-beta3 -> satisfiable by fxp/composer-asset-plugin[v1.0.0-beta3].
>           - fxp/composer-asset-plugin v1.0.0-beta3 requires composer-plugin-api 1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>        - A typo in the package name
>        - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>          see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Answer (score 2):

In my case project on Yii2

```
$ composer

  [ReflectionException]
  Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist


  [ErrorException]
  Declaration of Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository
  ::whatProvides() should be compatible with Composer\Repository\ComposerRepo
  sitory::whatProvides(Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool $pool, $name, $bypass
  Filters = false)
```

Yii2, in folder `vendor/fxp` you need to replace the folder `composer-asset-plugin` or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other solutions have worked for you, please try [AssetPackagist](https://asset-packagist.org) as an alternative.

1. Add the **packages** *bower-asset/bootstrap* and *npm-asset/jquery* to composer.json like the following:

   ```
   "require": {
       "bower-asset/bootstrap": "^3.3",
       "npm-asset/jquery": "^2.2"
   }
   ```
2. Add a **repositories** block (if you still don't have one, if you do, just append to it) with the following content:

   ```
   "repositories": [
       {
           "type": "composer",
           "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
       }
   ]
   ```
3. Run `composer install` (or `composer update`)
4. Considering that **asset-packagist** installs assets in a different directory, add the following lines to your application config (usually called as web.php):

   ```
   $config = [
       'aliases' => [
           '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
           '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
       ],
   ];
   ```

These instructions may change over time. They have been copied from the repo website so they could last in time just in case something happens to the website. I am not the author of the repo but I really appreciate the effort made into it. Please check https://asset-packagist.org/site/about to know more about the project.

---

If you are struggling with composer, here you have some useful commands:

`composer clear-cache` - Clear composer related caches

`composer install -vvv` - Add the parameter "vvv" to show installation process related output (useful to debug)

`composer global show` - Useful to check if you already have **fxp/composer-asset-plugin** installed. In my case, it already was, however it was not being detected as a dependency, and the solution I described earlier worked flawless to me - hope it does work for you too!

Answer (score -1):

You can make a permanent fix by requiring it at global level and then it's solved for every other project. But then make sure you give the tip to all your team members.

Best is to add this at project scope and it solves to everybody that way.

So:

`composer require fxp/composer-asset-plugin`