# Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist

Tags: yii2, composer-php

i installed latest version(1.0.3) of "fxp/composer-asset-plugin" and it now is

"fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "~1.0.3"

but when i run any command it gives me this error

> [ReflectionException] Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist
>
> [ErrorException] Declaration of Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository::whatProvides() should be compatible with Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository::whatProvides(Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool $pool, $name, $bypassFilters = false)

i run this command (php composer.phar global update fxp/composer-asset-plugin) but still this error occur!

and when i run this command (composer global require fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins) it show me

> Nothing to install or update

Here's my composer.json

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
"description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform": "*",
    "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "~1.0.3",
    "faravaghi/yii2-jalali-datepicker": "*",
    "farsidesign/yii2-jalali-datepicker": "dev-master",

},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `"fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest fxp/composer-asset-plugin version is [1.1.4](https://packagist.org/packages/fxp/composer-asset-plugin).

[Remove plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437837/composer-throw-reflectionexception-class-fxp-composer-assetplugin-repository-n) and install latest version. And don't forget update composer to [last version](https://getcomposer.org/download/).

Comment: thanks you but i said that (i run this command (php composer.phar global update fxp/composer-asset-plugin) but still this error occur!)

Comment: you have now fxp/composer-asset-plugin version 1.1.4?

Comment: no, i can't update it. it gives me "Nothing to install or update"

Comment: Delete composer plugin dir and reinstall it. See links above.

Comment: And remove string "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "~1.0.3" from composer.json!

Comment: where  is the composer plugin dir? how i can reinstall it?

Comment: /home/user/.composer

Comment: this address is in windows or linux? i want windows address.

Comment: c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\