# Cannot install packages via composer in yii2

Tags: yii2, composer-php

Every time when i try to install some package via composer in yii2. I have error like in picture.

[image: picture]

How can i fix this? Help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your advising! Compouser didn't accept any command the problem above had appear always. I think the problem appear after that i had change php.ini file. Problem solved by reinstaling Compouser and Xampp

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` to latest version (1.2.1) and composer to latest version (1.2.0).

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
composer selfupdate
```

Comment: I have the same problems. C:\xampp\htdocs\basic>composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"

Changed current directory to C:/Users/Sawyer/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Deprecation Notice: The Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\MultiConstraint class is
 deprecated, use Composer\Semver\Constraint\MultiConstraint instead. in phar://C
:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/LinkConstrain
t/MultiConstraint.php:17

Comment: Deprecation Notice: The Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\LinkConstraintInterface
interface is deprecated, use Composer\Semver\Constraint\ConstraintInterface inst
ead. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Packa
ge/LinkConstraint/LinkConstraintInterface.php:17


  [ReflectionException]
  Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist



  [ErrorException]

Comment: Declaration of Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository
  ::whatProvides() should be compatible with Composer\Repository\ComposerRepo
  sitory::whatProvides(Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool $pool, $name, $bypass
  Filters = false)


global <command-name> [<args>]...


C:\xampp\htdocs\basic>

Comment: Try `composer selfupdate` first. If it's not working remove the fxp plugin then update composer and then add fxp again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and then try to install packages

```
  php composer.phar global update fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-plugins
```

Comment: I try it and got. C:\xampp\htdocs>php composer.phar global update fxp/composer-asset-plugin --no-p
lugins
Changed current directory to C:/Users/Sawyer/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

C:\xampp\htdocs>
composer.phar(only composer work) doesn't work in directory of my project thus i try it in htdocs

Comment: Follow this link .. Might be helpful to you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437837/composer-throws-reflectionexception-class-fxp-composer-assetplugin-repository?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

json file in your localhost and put your code in that

and then run command line and go to the composer.json directory

and then write composer init then cmd help you to continue the way

Comment: when i write composer init in the directory of my project i have the same errors like above