# composer update Errors, [ReflectionException] Class Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I'm getting an error while trying to install any plugin.

I have tried to remove:

```
composer global remove "fxp/composer-asset-plugin"
```

And then update it again:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:*"
```

But I am still getting the following errors:

> Deprecation Notice: The
>   Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\MultiConstraint class is deprecated,
>   use Composer\Semver\Constraint\MultiConstraint instead. in
>   phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/LinkConstraint/MultiConstraint.php:17
>   Deprecation Notice: The
>   Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\LinkConstraintInterface interface is
>   deprecated, use Composer\Semver\Constraint\ConstraintInterface
>   instead. in
>   phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/LinkConstraint/LinkConstraintInterface.php:17
>
> [ReflectionException]   Class
>   Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository does not exist
>
> [ErrorException]   Declaration of
>   Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository::whatProvides(Composer\DependencyResolv
>   er\Pool $pool, $name) should be compatible with
>   Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository::whatProvides(Composer\Depen
>   dencyResolver\Pool $pool, $name, $bypassFilters = false)

Can anyone help me figure out what am I doing wrong and how to solve it?

Here is my `composer.json`

```
"minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "2amigos/yii2-date-picker-widget": "~1.0",      "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",         "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",       "cebe/js-search": "~0.9",       "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "@dev",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-develop"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset":{
            "installer-paths": {
                "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
                "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
            }
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Have you tried `composer selfupdate` as well? You could also try `composer global clearcache` before requiring fxp/composer-asset-plugin. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36438171/57091)

Comment: You may also want to try https://asset-packagist.org/ in order to avoid fxp/composer-asset-plugin.

Comment: its doesnt work dude, its still getting  erros, composer global clearcache its work but nothing change on it, and anyway i already added http://asset=packagist.org on my composer.json and still nothing change

Comment: i reinstall composer and its work normal, thanks for helping